# Pip3 no funciona con python 3.10 y si con python 3.8

Tags: python, pip

acabo de actualizar a python 3.10 , yo usaba normalmente python 3.8 (que sigue instalado)

El problema me surge con pip cuando cambio como predeterminado a python 3.10 , pip ya no funciona, si pongo como predeterminado python 3.8 sigue funcionando perfectamente pip.

Asumo que es una cuestion de path o de configuracion a librerias en pip, pero no logro determinar donde hacer la modificacion.

Gracias.

Comment: ¡No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
```

Esto soluciono mi problema